# Pop to Root ViewController in Tab bar Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, tabs

I have tabBar Application in which i have added Tab-bar on my SignViewController i have 3 different tabs in my setting Tab i have logOut Button on than button click i want to pop tab bar and jump back to my SignViewController. can any one help in this small issue Please

Comment: why don't you make your SignViewController a modal view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to just understand flow of app what you are doing.

First you are running application using `rootviewcontroller`.

when you get login success you just assign `rootviewcontroller = tabbarcontroller.view`, right?

so What you need is that when you want to logout from app then just assign same rootviewto main `rootviewcontroller`. no need to do any thing.

Or if you are adding as `subviews` to window then use add and remove methods like

```
[self.window addSubview:rootview];
[tabbar removefromSuperview];
```

i hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanx, it's working fine. But it's not releasing the memory. so what to do now?

Comment: Hello Tapas,
If you want to release memory then you have to release tabbar but as i know it will crash if you do that. So its good to keep like whatever it is.

Answer (score 0):

Use SignviewController as root for navigation. Then you can use method

```
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:signViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Have u used one root navigation controller and then tab bars or in each tab bar separate navigation controllers?